# Wordpress: two types of comments? or multiple taxonomies?

Tags: php, wordpress

My idea is to have a page where two authors can post multiple posts (in the page) and other visitors can comment the whole page:

I had in mind a very simple (hack) approach which is:

1. Having a custom "page" that has all the posts of a category and that page can be commented
2. Having a page where two people edit the content (but then the multiple posts are faked by being one page only being modified) and normal comments for the page
3. Use of taxonomies (which I am not very used to) and create a custom taxonomy where you can post and comment, any hint on this one?

Is there any better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a great plugin for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagely-multiedit/

If you don't want to use the plugin, you can carve out the functional code.

Let me know if you have any other questions/issues regarding this or if it doesn't fully solve your goal.